# how to insert postgresql into laravel model

Tags: laravel, postgresql

I have a postgresql code like this and it runs correctly but I'm confused to enter the laravel model

postgresql :

```
select * from anggota a where id_parpol = 4 and a.nik in ('2816742691102816','8939799808489659','4757527446829790') or a.no_kta in ('2816742691102816','8939799808489659','4757527446829790')
```

anggotaContoller :

```
$aa = "2816742691102816,8939799808489659,4757527446829790";
$bb = explode(",", $aa);
$model = Anggota::where('id_parpol', Auth::user()->id_org)->whereIn('nik', $bb)->whereIn('no_kta', $bb)->get();
dd($model);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use closure based grouping of queries

```
$model = Anggota::where('id_parpol', Auth::user()->id_org)
   ->where(function($query) use($bb){
        $query->whereIn('nik', $bb)
               ->orWhereIn('no_kta', $bb);
})->get();
```

Comment: @SyahrulRomadoni `->where(function ($query) use ($bb) {`

Comment: Sorry, updated my answer

Comment: Sorry, that was correct, I just wanted to ask, then I deleted it because it didn't happen